# convert to much faster loop with offset

Tags: excel, vba

just wondering if there is a much faster loop than the loop below,what its doing is from sheet1 B check if E is blank then compare B of sheet1 on B of sheet2 with trim-replace if true enter value to both E of sheet1 and sheet2, just over 1.5K rows and its taking about 10 seconds

```
Sub CompareData()

Dim lastRowSht1 As Long, lastRowSht2 As Long
Dim sht1Rng As Range, sht2Rng As Range
Dim sht1Cell As Range, sht2Cell As Range
Dim sht1Val As String, sht2Val As String

lastRowSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set sht2Rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & lastRowSht2)
Set sht1Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastRowSht1)

        For Each sht1Cell In sht1Rng
            If sht1Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then
                sht1Val = Replace(Trim(sht1Cell.Value), " ", "")
                For Each sht2Cell In sht2Rng
                    sht2Val = Replace(Trim(sht2Cell.Value), " ", "")
                    If sht1Val = sht2Val Then
                        sht1Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "PARTIAL"
                        sht2Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "PARTIAL"
                    End If
                 Next sht2Cell
            End If
        Next sht1Cell
```

Comment: Are the values in column B unique ?

Comment: Maybe try to make a range variable with blank value for column E. Something like `set rgBlankSh1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E" & lastRowSht1).specialcells(xlblanks)`, the same for sheet 2, make rgBlankSh2. Then loop where each looped cell.offset(0,-3) you make `sht1Val = Replace(Trim(sht1Cell.Value), " ", "")`. So it doesn't need to check if the looped cell.offset(0,3) is blank but directly create sht1Val when loop inside rgBlankSh1. Seeing your code, made me assume that if (for example) sheet1 cell E10, E15, E35 is blank, then it surely sheet2 cell E10, E15, E35 also blank. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Reading cell-by-cell is much slower than (eg) reading all data into an array, then looping over the array.

Comment: Filter `Sheet1` in column `E` (`5`) by an empty string and use *Range.SpecialCells* and *Range.Replace* to replace in one go. Reference column `B` in `Sheet2` and do the *Range.Replace* in one go. Now you can choose what to do. Cell by cell is still horribly slow. Using *Range.Find* is a bit faster, using `Application.Match` even more so. But using arrays, as illustrated in the answer by Tim Williams, is the king. it is also important to reveal which column has unique values as asked by CDP1802, which would help to write a possibly more efficient code.

Comment: @CDP1802 B is unique for each sheet yes, used the answer of Tim, thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be much faster - read all values into arrays, and then process the arrays, instead of reading cell-by-cell.

```vb
Sub CompareData()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim arr1, arr2, arrRes1, arrRes2, r1 As Long, r2 As Long, v1, v2
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("B2:B" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    arr1 = rng1.Value                 'values to check
    CleanValues arr1                  'pre-clean values
    arrRes1 = rng1.Offset(0, 3).Value 'result values
    
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B2:B" & ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    arr2 = rng2.Value                 'values to check
    CleanValues arr2                  'pre-clean values
    arrRes2 = rng2.Offset(0, 3).Value 'result values
    
    For r1 = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If Len(arrRes1(r1, 1)) = 0 Then
            v1 = arr1(r1, 1)
            For r2 = 1 To UBound(arr2)
                If v1 = arr2(r2, 1) Then
                    arrRes1(r1, 1) = "PARTIAL"
                    arrRes2(r2, 1) = "PARTIAL"
                End If
            Next r2
        End If
    Next r1
    'write the results back to the sheet
    rng1.Offset(0, 3).Value = arrRes1
    rng2.Offset(0, 3).Value = arrRes2
End Sub

'Trim and remove spaces from array values
'(assumes single-column 2D array input)
Sub CleanValues(arr)
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        arr(r, 1) = Replace(Trim(arr(r, 1)), " ", "")
    Next r
End Sub
```